# Override a parameter in the parameters.json file with PowerShell when deploying ARM template

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I am using Azure PowerShell to deploy an ARM templates but want to override a parameter in the parameters.json file at **runtime**

Is there a way to do this?

eg I use `get-azurermresource` to get the virtual network name into a variable called `$vnetName`
I then want to pass this variable `$vnetName` to replace the parameters for Vnet Name in the azuredeploy.parameters.json file

Answer (score 9):

To overwrite the paramter at **runtime** you can just specify it when invoking the `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet:

```
 New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment `
  -TemplateFile D:\tmp\azuredeploy.json `
  -TemplateParameterFile D:\tmp\azuredeploy.json `
  -<yourParameterNameHere> $vnetName `
  -ResourceGroupName myRg
```

You could also permanently overwrite the json file itself using PowerShell:

```
$paramFile = Get-Content d:\tmp\azuredeploy.parameters.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$paramFile.parameters.vnetName.value = $vnetName 
$paramFile | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content d:\tmp\azuredeploy.parameters.json
```